# Hide gravity forms

Tags: get-posts, plugin-gravity-forms

I have gravity forms set up on my site and I am wanting to hide/show a form based on whether or not the user has posted an entry into the form/database.
If they have made an entry, then I want to hide it and display some simple text.

I see that gravity forms allow you to limit number of entries but this is not quite what I am after.

I'm guessing I would have to query the database but I'm not really sure the best way to write it.
Would I have to use something like get_posts and check if the author has an entry? Would this be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
<?php 

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( count_user_posts( $user->ID ) >= 1 ) {

        // echo your text snippet

    } else {

        // echo your form

    }

?>
```

1) `wp_get_current_user()` returns the `WP_User` object which includes many properties for that user.

2) Since we only want the ID of the current user, we assign a variable of choice, in this instance `$user` which is equal to that of i.e. `$user = wp_get_current_user()`.

3) Then we can grab the current user ID simply by declaring `$user->ID`

4) We pass `$user->ID` to our `count_user_posts( $user->ID)` function which is then measured against our condition being greater than or equal to 1 post.

5) Do your thing...

References:

- [Codex: wp_get_current_user](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user)
- [Codex: count_user_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    global $wpdb;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $sql = "SELECT id from " . $wpdb->prefix . "rg_lead WHERE created_by=" . $user->ID;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    if (count($results) > 0) {
        // An entry is made by the user for any form
    }
    else{ 
         // Show form
    }
```

If you know form id for example $form_id then use

```
$sql = "SELECT id from " . $wpdb->prefix . "rg_lead WHERE created_by=" . $user->ID . " AND form_id=" . $form_id;
```